# My request to an API doesn't work with ajax (err:500), despite working with postman

Tags: ajax, api, postman

I need some help to use an API (Easy!Appointment).
I try to use some ajax code to create a new customer profile from my site into the API database, but I receive an error 500.
I send the same request by postman and it worked.
I already use a GET type request with ajax to display some info from the datadase into my site view and it worked juste fine too.
I have only problem with the POST request, from my site.

Can you help me to make it work ? Thanks ! :-)

Here the ajax code who doesn't work :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/easyappointment-test/index.php/api/v1/customers",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "firstName": "John", 
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "email": "jo...@doe2.com", 
        "phone": "0123456789"
    },
    headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer dbhf6da4ew7nw79bhvaays', 
        "Content-Type" :'application/json'},
    success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help ! :-) 
PS : Sorry for my poor english !

Comment: What's the error in console

Comment: :-) Here the error : POST http://localhost/easyappointment-test/index.php/api/v1/customers
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 35ms]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stringify data before sending

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/easyappointment-test/index.php/api/v1/customers",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "firstName": "John", 
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "email": "jo...@doe2.com", 
        "phone": "0123456789"
    }),
    headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer dbhf6da4ew7nw79bhvaays', 
        "Content-Type" :'application/json'},
    success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```